# Prove that no interval has Lebesgue measure zero

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

I have proved that if $I_1,\cdots,I_k$ are open sub-intervals of $[a,b]$, then $|I_1 \cup \cdots \cup I_k| \leq |I_1|+...+|I_k|$, where |I|=length of the interval I. Assuming $m[a,b]=0$. Given $\epsilon>0$, then $|I_1|+\cdots+|I_k| < \epsilon $ and $|[a,b]|=|I_1 \cup \cdots \cup I_k|+|a|+|b|=|I_1 \cup \cdots \cup I_k|=b-a$, arriving at a contradiction.

Is this correct?

Comment: The first equality in the last line does not hold. the terms $|a|+|b|$ are unnecessary. Other than that it looks good.

Comment: @Yanko Thanks. I was thinking that since $I_1,\cdots,I_k$ are open intervals it would not contain {a,b}

Comment: Actually it should, because it is a cover. But either way the length of $\{a,b\}$ is zero.

Comment: This implies" not Jordan measure 0", not " not Lebesgue measure 0". Also we know that J-measure 0 sets are L-measure 0 sets, thus sets has L-measure $\neq 0$ implies it has J-measure $\neq 0$. That being said, your proof is not complete.

Comment: What are you using as your definition of Lebesgue measure?

Comment: @Driver8 $S$ is of Lebesgue measure zero iff for every $\epsilon >0$, there exists a countable collection of open intervals $I_1,I_2,\cdots,$ each of finite length such that $S \subseteq \bigcup_1^{\infty}I_i$ and $\sum_1^{\infty}|I_i|<\epsilon$

Comment: @xbh I am not sure if I understood your comment correctly. Are you saying that I have showed that it cannot have Jordan measure 0?

Comment: Hint: note that $I$ covers itself and that if $J$ is properly contained in $I$, then $J$ does not cover $I$. Now use your definition.

Comment: @Whocares Yes, but that result does not imply that $[a,b]$ cannot have L-measure 0, so you need to improve the proof.